# C++ Backend, Objective C frontend, NULL nil problem

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've got an interesting problem that I am sure someone would have come across. I am writing the front end UI in Objective C Cocoa, and the backend in C++. In C++ I have

```
#define NULL 0
```

Unfortunately, this has dire consequences for nil. Especially with nil terminated function calls as I now get this warning - "Missing sentinel in method dispatch", which I assume means it couldn't find the nil terminator. This is the only definition I could find for nil:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL    __DARWIN_NULL
#endif /* ! NULL */
#ifndef nil
    #define nil NULL
#endif /* ! nil */
```

which seems to me that nil is NULL, and that my earlier define for NULL is messing everything up although I don't know how. The NULL is defined in C++ so that it can be platform independent. I have tried redefining NULL and nil, but nothing seems to take. Any suggestions on the correct way to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do... but could show a specific example?

Comment: Basically 'nil' stops working correctly once I used #define NULL 0. So things like [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColorsAndLocations:... nil] would not work with that define. But the define is needed in the backend.

Comment: Why do you even need that definition? C++ code can just use `0`; the `NULL` macro is there only for backwards compatibility with C.

Answer (score 4):

In either C or C++, attempting to define `NULL` yourself leads to undefined behavior. Sorry, but you're just allowed to do that. Instead of trying to define it yourself, you *need* to include one of the headers that already defines it for you.

Comment: I think it's quite specific to this case because C++ code can co-exist with Objective C code. For example, if I decided to use a Java front end, or a Javascript frontend, NULL would not be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Reminded me of this question I saw recently: [How to wrap a C++ lib in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799169/how-to-wrap-a-c-lib-in-objective-c)

So, what about:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL 0
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could #define it while it is being used within your .h/.cpp.  Then, at the end of those files, `#undef NULL` so that the ObjC's definitions take over.  That way the definition is cleaned-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use `0` in C++ instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Then you as the human programmer run into the same problem the Objective-C compiler is having: Did you mean to pass a zero there, or the null pointer constant? Goes triple in function and C++ method calls, where the arguments aren't named in the call, so you can't always tell whether something expects a number or a pointer. `NULL` and `nil` exist for this reason.

Comment: Well, `NULL` is just a `#define`, so it doesn't really serve any purpose (except making the code a bit clearer, for some people). Personally, I prefer to use 0, just as Stroustrup (IIRC), but that's more a question of style than of substance. C++0x offers `nullptr`, which is a better alternative (it is type safe, i.e. you cannot use it as argument of a function that expects an `int`, and it's as clear as `NULL`).